# Create SQLDump from MariaDB directory

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know this is a bit strange question but my database decided to leave me today, I tried migrating it but it gives me the same error, it can't start. So, I have still access to the MariaDB directory and I managed to make a backup of the /var/lib/mysql directory, anyway, if I move the entire directory to the new server I get the same error and if I move just individual databases I get the "table not in engine" error... I would like to create a mysqldump using the MYI, frm, idb.. files. Otherwise I would like to understand a way to solve the table not in engine problem. Thanks in advance

EDIT: Oh and I've tried restoring an old backup and replacing the frm.. files but it threw another error, I don't remember the exact error but it was like "table size not in engine" or "column size not in engine"

Comment: Did you change versions during the move?  Were you using MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?

Comment: Didn't change the version, anyway I was using InnoDB, it's actually InnoDB that seems broken...

Comment: When dumping InnoDB tables, you must include `ibdata1` and all the table-related files.  More simply -- the entire tree.  We need to see the section of the log with the actual error message.